# Multiple X11 forwardings on ubuntu and jupyter-notebook

Tags: 18.04, ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding, jupyter

I have installed jupyter-notebook on an ubuntu 18.04; let us call it *Server A*. The Jupyter Notebook is an open-source web application that allows you to create and share documents that contain live code, equations, visualizations, and narrative text. I successfully establish SSH to *server A* initiated by my client ( *Client B*). I am able to visually forward X11 running of Firefox to *Client B* using the below command.

```
On Client B:
SSH -X@Server A ip Address
user1# firefox &
```

Now, Inside the jupyter-notebook in firefox tab, I am able to execute a GUI-based application - I am able to run Linux shell command inside the firefox tab(jupyter-notebook session).

```
!xclock
```

The problem is that the xclock is executed on the *Server A* successfully, but it is not forwarded to a new X11 window on the *Client B*. Is it possible to forward xclock(GUI Application), which is initiated by the jupyter-notebook session (firefox tab) to *client B*, while the firefox is also initiated by SSH connection from *Client B*?

Comment: What user on Server A is running the Jupyter notebook server?

Comment: @BrianTurek: The root user.